# Superimpose Line Styles With Parametric Coloring

Tags: plotting

My aim is to plot each function with distinct style superimpose with color based upon parameter.

For instance, I have 3 functions of 1 variable and 1 parameter. Table command is used for iterating over parameter space & also for colouring the associated curve obtained from the Plot command. All 3 functions are plotted with 3 distinct plot style.

I would like to know a better version (a more simple without using **Style** command) to do the following:

```
{k1, k2, dk} = {0.01, 0.09, 0.01};

f1[x_] = Sin[k x];
f2[x_] = Cos[k x];
f3[x_] = Sin[k x]*Cos[k x];

Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Style[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)]], {k, k1, k2, 
    dk}]], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}], Dashing[0.004]},
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image: Thanks to @Chris Degnen for legend corrections.]

Comment: Looks good to me, except for the legend. Your code takes nice advantage of `Plot`'s processing of `Style`. (Actually, I didn't know it was this robust at handling lists of styled lists.) What do you want for the legend, anyway? Or do you find it acceptable?

Comment: For legend I use Barlegend...Its just to know from Mathematica experts are there better ways to do this when there are multiple functions depending on multiple parameters.

Comment: I meant, do the different colors bother you? Or do you not care what colors the legend shows?

Comment: Legend colors do matter but only to show the parametric variation of considered functions which are shown distinctly by different dashing styles.

Answer (score 1):

Including a legend for `k`

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

{k1, k2, dk} = {0.01, 0.09, 0.01};

f1[x_] = Sin[k x];
f2[x_] = Cos[k x];
f3[x_] = Sin[k x]*Cos[k x];

color[k_] := ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[k, {k1, k2}]]

Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[Style[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, color[k]],
   {k, k1, k2, dk}]], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
 PlotStyle ->
  {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}], Dashing[0.004]},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"},
 PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[
    Subscript["Amp", #] & /@ {1, 2, 3},
    {Right, Bottom}],
   LineLegend[color /@ Range[k1, k2, dk],
    Range[k1, k2, dk],
    LegendLabel -> Style["k =", 14]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code becomes too lengthy & a little more complex & here BarLegend will look more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use `Style`, here is another option

```
styles = 
  Flatten[Table[{ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)], d}, {k, k1,
      k2, dk}, {d, {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}], 
      Dashing[0.004]}}], 1];

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {k, k1, k2, dk}], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> styles, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are using Table command TWO times...for multiple functions depending on multiple parameters it will be an additional resources overload.